# Better way to get a JCR Session object in my Spring MVC Magnolia module that LifeTimeJCRSessionUtil

Tags: java, jcr, magnolia

I am using the following code to get a JCR Session inside my Magnolia module:

```
LifeTimeJCRSessionUtil.getSession("magicWorkspace");
```

I'm not using Guice to do IoC. Is this the best way to get hold of a JCR session in a Magnolia module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended way is using the static methods on MgnlContext. Like so:

```
Session session = MgnlContext.getJCRSession(RepositoryConstants.WEBSITE)
```

In `RepositoryConstants` you'll find constants for the standard JCR workspaces used in Magnolia.